# webpack-dev-server won't start with selected network hostname (on OSX)

Tags: macos, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using [hjs-webpack](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack) and running the dev server at hostname `mycomputer.local`. It has always worked before, but now when I try to start the server, I get this error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND rainbow.local
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

If I remove the line specifying `hostname: 'mycomputer.local'` from the webpack config file, it launches fine at `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I figured out my Mac had recently changed the network address from `mycomputer.local` to `mycomputer-2.local`. I was able to change it back by editing this setting back to `mycomputer.local` under `System Preferences > Sharing`.